# prawn pdf rendering partial results in blank page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I try to use rails prawn template style. In my main prawn document "order_summary", I want to render a prawn template like this:

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4")
render :partial => "invoice"
```

The name of the partial is: _invoice.pdf.prawn and resides in the very same folder as the main document.

When running it, it results in a blank page. The page was rendered successfully according to the logs:

> Rendered documents/_invoice.pdf.prawn (756.7ms) Rendered
>   documents/order_summary.pdf.prawn (1100.9ms) Completed 200 OK in
>   2323ms (Views: 1141.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

If I run the partial as "invoice.pdf.prawn" (without rendering it through another file), it works fine so I assume there is no code error or sth.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is a gotcha documented in the [Prawnto wiki](https://github.com/GetJobber/prawnto/wiki/Partials). Even if the partial is in the same folder, you still have to specify the full path. In your case, 'documents/invoice'.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the only way to use partials I'm Prawn is by using gems like prawnto or prawn rails?